# Print arguments to printf in no particular order

Tags: coreutils, printf

How can I refer back to arguments to `coreutil`'s `printf` in no particular order?

This is what I want to avoid:

```
$ printf '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s' a c a c b c a
a c a c b c a
```

This is what I would like to do:

```
$ printf '%s %s³ %s¹ %s³ %s² %s³ %¹' a b c
a c a c b c a
```

This is how to do it with Perl.

```
perl -e 'printf ("%s %3\$s %1\$s %3\$s %2\$s %3\$s %1\$s\n", 'a', 'b', 'c');'
a c a c b c a
```

Notice only four arguments are passed to `printf`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `printf` and not `echo "[ -d $dir ] || mkdir $dir; cd $dir"`?

Comment: Yes, but mine was a bad example. I rephrased the question so that I think it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in way to do this that I was able to find. You can always generate the arguments in a loop like this:

#### for loop

```
$ printf '[ -d %s ] || mkdir %s; cd %s\n' `for run in {1..3}; do echo "$dir";done`
```

Slight variance:

```
$ printf '[ -d %s ] || mkdir %s; cd %s\n' $(for run in {1..3}; do echo "$dir";done)
```

You can control the number of arguments by changing this part of the command `{1..3}`.

#### seq & xargs

```
$ printf '[ -d %s ] || mkdir %s; cd %s\n' $(seq 1 3 | { xargs -i -- echo "$dir"; })
```

This will create a seq of numbers, 1 to 3, and this controls how many times the { xargs -i ... } will execute.

#### yes

Thanks to @rici's comment you can also use this construct, `yes ... | head -n 3`:

```
$ printf '[ -d %s ] || mkdir %s; cd %s\n' $(yes "$dir" | head -n 3)
```

#### References

- [How to repeat a shell command N times](http://www.stefanoforenza.com/how-to-repeat-a-shell-command-n-times/)

Comment: more concisely: `$(yes "blah" | head -n 3)'. But neither that nor your answer will work if `blah` contains `$IFS` characters.

Comment: @rici - yeah I forgot to guard the strings with quotes, I've fixed that. Thanks for the `yes ... | head ...` construct. I was trying something with `seq ... | { xargs ... }` which is similar but your's is more compact.

Answer (score 1):

Printf in bash doesn't have that option implemented.

But a simple solution is to use variables:

```
$ a=a b=b c=c
$ printf '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n' "$a" "$c" "$a" "$c" "$b" "$c" "$a"
a c a c b c a
```

Or even the positional parameters:

```
$ set -- a b c
$ printf '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n' "$1" "$3" "$1" "$3" "$2" "$3" "$1"
a c a c b c a
```